# sqoop incremantal count the difference

Tags: sql, hive, sqoop, sqoop2

I want to import all new lines of my table using sqoop to hive table, the problem that i dont have column to use for my incremantal update.

- So i try to count all lignes of my table and i store it into hive with a timestamp column.
- Than i select the max of that number and compare it to the number of lines of my source table.

My question is, how to use sqoop to import just that diffence between my hive table and my source table?

Comment: Does db table have time stamp column?

Comment: Can you check if the table has last modified column?

Comment: @IskuskovAlexander no my bd dosnt have a timestamp column

Comment: @SandeepSingh no i can't know the the last modified column

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to left join the two dataset by some columns or all columns and then find where the right side is null so that we have only new records to be loaded
You can follow these steps

```
1) The initial load data (previous day data) is in hdfs  - Relation A
2) Import the current data into HDFS using sqoop -- Relation B
3) Use pig Load the above two hdfs directories in relation A and B define schema.
4) Convert them to tuples and join them by all columns
5) The join result will have two tuples in each row((A,B),(A,B)) , fetch the result from join where tuple B is null ((A,D),).
6) Now flatten the join by tuple A you will have new/updated records(A,D).
```

Comment: thank you @vinayak_narune ; is there a solution without going through pig? just using sqoop and hive

Comment: the above can be implemented using sqoop and hive to, its just joining two tables and getting results.